# Making my dream bike come true

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, gears, suspension, lighting

my name is Benjamin and for quite some time now i have been riding my bicycle to college and other places. The bike i have now is only very simple but has saved as a great alternative for transport and is just simplify great to ride. Having ridden my bike so many times for so long i have now started to grow a taste of what kinda bike i would like to have, my dream bike. The features i would like for my next bike to have would be as followed:

- (27 gears) making going up hill much easier and going down hill much faster.
- (Efficient front and rear brakes) ensuring full controller over the bike.
- (FOX XTD REMOTE LEVER) to adjust bikes suspensions for any journey ahead.
- (Remote lever seat post) for maximum comfort when riding on rough terrains.
- (Generated back wheel) to supply power to front and back lights.
- (large rear rack) to allow for transportation such as bags.
- (Onboard lock for back wheel) to allow for added security.
- (Onboard portable pump) to ensure good inflation for tires.
- (reflectors including wheels) for added visibility.
- (battery powered lights) for having to stop in dark where path is not available.

Crazy i know! but as you can see with me wanting such a pasific bike with all these features finding such bike is just impossible leaving me to this question.HOW IN HELL DO I GET SUCH BIKE? is there some place where this beast of a bike can be made? or would i be better off buying a bike and instilling these upgrades my self? if i do take the second option how would i have to go about it and what would i have to do step wise and be wary of?

Super exited to hearing what you guys have to say to my questions and thank you.

Comment: What people usually end up with, is buying more than one bike. One without much (ore maybe better, any) suspension, but fitted with a rack to transport things. One MTB to go up and down trails. One road bike to go fast. One single speed, just for fun. One ... you get the idea.

Comment: A "portable pump" is easy -- get a decent frame pump.  And there are many options for reflectors and lights.  Racks can be added to many bikes, but are a problem on bikes with rear suspension.  27 gears is available but is more than you really need.  There are multiple options for brakes.  Buy the bike with the gears, brakes, and suspension you want and then add the other features.

Comment: Sounds like a blend of a touring bike and a full-suspension mountain bike.   Have you considered a trailer rather than carrying all your stuff on the bike?  Do you intend on doing long multi-day rides (lean toward touring) or more off-road trips?  Or both all the time?

Comment: it would be better if you put more effort into basic English and less into profanity. I'm voting to close because the OP has exited.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Honestly i have 2 of what you describe with a few variations - for gearing you don't need more than 2X11.  Light i would consider looking at a dynamo hub like SON 28.  Rear rack look at Thule, bike pannier rack (use to be called Freeload).

Suspension and dropper post these days come almost standard on most bikes and you don't need to go spend $7k plus to get one either.

I would buy an out of the box bike and change that you want to change by sourcing parts from Chain Reaction Cycle or get your local bike shop to custom build you one.

Comment: Curious why Im being marked down on this without any explanation.